# How to use the value of a function within the same function

Tags: python

I am trying to create a loop that will randomly generate numbers until reaching some condition (e.g. > 16). How do I use a value, obtained using a function I created, within that same function? The only options I can think of are using 'return' and 'print' but they don't seem to work.

Here's an example of what I've come up with so far:

```
>>> def y():
...     x = random.randint(1,24)
...     print(x)                  (I've also tried 'return x' at this line)
...     while int(x) < 16:
...             return x
```

Comment: You're picking a single random number _outside_ the loop - `print(x)` and `return x` _are_ how to use that value, but they won't _change_ it.

Comment: Pick a random number. While it's under 16, continue to pick a random number. *Then* return the number after the loop (which will terminate when the number is > 16). Of course, in this particular case, you'd just do `return random.randint(16, 24)` to begin with…

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator:

```
def y():
    while True:
        x = random.randint(1, 24)
        if x >= 16:
            return
        yield x

for i in y():
    print(i)

# Output:
1
14
10
```